# .txx intelligence and autocompletion in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete

I have a simple project with .cxx, .h and .txx files which is generated from Cmake. By changing adding the file extension in the Text Editor Option, now VS2010 can treat it as a .cxx file. However, the codes in .txx file still cannot autocomplete:

```
    addFilter->Update(); // No hint when I type add, also when call the member
```

This is OK in .cxx file. Does anyone know what's happening?

Thanks in advance,
Julio

Answer (score 1):

The Intellisense should locate and parse these files if you add them to the included extensions:

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Project Settings
Append “.txx” to the Extensions to include item
```

Comment: It is not working... In fact, the file was already included after I set property in CMake.

Comment: Which property did you set in CMAKE, and when you say "file was already included" do you mean that the txx extension was already included in the VC++ Project Settings?

Comment: "set_source_files_properties" to set .txx, then "set" the source files. I can see the file in the VS left column. I further included .txx extension in VC++ Project Settings but it didn't change anything.

Comment: That's the usual way of adding extensions to a project, but Intellisense is known to be finicky. Here's another suggestion - try deleting the `.suo` file for the project (or regenerating the project entirely cleanly with cmake).

Comment: It's not working... Thanks anyway, I'll try to see if there's other way.

Comment: Worked for me in VS2017, just needed to restart VS after changing the setting.